# Javascript básico

Tags: javascript

Buenas recién estoy empezando en esto de la programacion en Javascript y tengo este ejercicio el cual deberia de resolver de una forma mas limpia si alguien puede ayudarme y explicarme la otra solucion estaria agradecido

```
 function naipes(tipoDePalo){
 let cartas = []


 for ( let i = 1; i <= 12; i++ ){

 if(tipoDePalo === "basto") {


 cartas.push(i +" "+ "de basto")
 } else if (tipoDePalo === "espadas") {
cartas.push(i + " " + "de espadas" )
} else if (tipoDePalo === "oro") {
cartas.push(i + " " + "de oro" )
} else if (tipoDePalo === "copa") {
cartas.push(i + " " + "de copa" )
} 
}
mazo = cartas.splice(7, 2)
return cartas

}
```

El ejercicio dice asi:
Queremos escribir una función naipes, que dado un palo, devuelva una lista de strings, una por cada carta de ese palo según los naipes de la baraja española:
naipes("espadas")
["1 de espadas", "2 de espadas", "3 de espadas" ..., "12 de espadas"]
Tomá en cuenta que los naipes de la baraja española incluyen todas las numeradas del 1 al 12, pero para éste ejercicio no queremos incluir los 8 y los 9.

Comment: La pregunta parece algo amplia, lee [ask]

Comment: Esta pregunta está basada en opiniones, por lo que seguramente terminará cerrada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

para mejorar un poco la función mi propuesta seria que aprovechases el argumento de la funcion (`tipoDePalo`) para generar los nombres de las cartas. También podrias usar el metodo `.map()` presente en [Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/ca/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objectes_globals/Array/map) en lugar del for loop. Finalmente, usando [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/ca/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) permite leer mejor el código cuando estas manipulando strings. El resultado seria algo así:

```
function naipes (tipoDePalo) {
    let cartas = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12];
    return cartas.map( carta => `${carta} de ${tipoDePalo}` );
```

Se podría llegar a convertir en una "one-line" aunque luego puede que sea mas difícil de entender lo que se está haciendo:

```
const naipes = palo => [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12].map(c => `${c} de ${palo}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para formar la frase no hace falta comprobar la variable tipodepalo en cada iteración, ya que no va a variar, puedes usar directamente la variable.
Si quieres puedes comprobar antes del bucle si tipodepalo contiene un string válido.
Además, puedes saltarte el 8 y 9 usando un condicional en vez de eliminarlos después.

```js
function naipes(tipoDePalo){
  if (  tipoDePalo == "sotas" ||
        tipoDePalo == "bastos" ||
        tipoDePalo == "espadas" ||
        tipoDePalo == "copas" )
  {
    let cartas = [] ;
    for ( let i = 1; i <= 12; i++ )
    {
      if (i != 8 && i != 9)
      {
        cartas.push(i +" de "+tipoDePalo);
      }
    }
    return cartas;
  }
}
console.log(naipes("copas"));
```

Nota: Todo y que la respuesta de Guillem es más optima y elegante, siendo un ejercicio de iniciación al JavaScript, entiendo que el profesor va a esperar una respuesta de este tipo, aun así, investiga la otra respuesta, que es más interesante.